# Use Python to print sentences belonging to most common words in a document

Tags: python, nlp, nltk, hashtag

I have a text document, I am using `regex` and `nltk` to find top `5` most common words from this document. I have to print out sentences where these words belong to, how do I do that? further, I want to extend this to finding common words in multiple documents and returning their respective sentences.

```
import nltk
import collections
from collections import Counter

import re
import string

frequency = {}
document_text = open('test.txt', 'r')
text_string = document_text.read().lower()
match_pattern = re.findall(r'\b[a-z]{3,15}\b', text_string) #return all the words with the number of characters in the range [3-15]

fdist = nltk.FreqDist(match_pattern) # creates a frequency distribution  from a list
most_common = fdist.max()    # returns a single element
top_five = fdist.most_common(5)# returns a list

list_5=[word for (word, freq) in fdist.most_common(5)]


print(top_five)
print(list_5)
```

Output:

```
[('you', 8), ('tuples', 8), ('the', 5), ('are', 5), ('pard', 5)]
['you', 'tuples', 'the', 'are', 'pard']
```

The output is most commonly occurring words I have to print sentences where these words belong to, how do I do that?

Answer (score 4):

Although it doesn't account for special characters at word boundaries like your code does, the following would be a starting point:

```
for sentence in text_string.split('.'):
    if list(set(list_5) & set(sentence.split(' '))):
        print sentence
```

We first iterate over the sentences, assuming each sentence ends with a `.` and the `.` character is nowhere else in the text. Afterwards, we print the sentence if the [intersection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_(set_theory)) of its set of words with the set of words in your `list_5` is not empty.

Comment: how to remove additional parts, the output of your code is  :;}{\levelnumbers\'01;}\fi-360\li720\lin720 }{\listname ;}\listid1}}
{\*\listoverridetable{\listoverride\listid1\listoverridecount0\ls1}}
\margl1440\margr1440\vieww14360\viewh11020\viewkind0
\deftab720
\f0\fs32 \cf2 \cb3 \expnd0\expndtw0\kerning0
\outl0\strokewidth0 \strokec2 in my previous refreshers, which you can access from the series navigation links at the top of this article, i talked about two important python concepts you need to grasp in order to move forward in your python learning journey
\'a0\

Comment: quick note: My text file starts as follows: "In my previous refreshers, which you can access from the series navigation links at the top of this article, I talked about two important Python concepts you need to grasp in order to move forward in your Python learning journey."

Answer (score 2):

You will have to install NLTK Data if you haven't already done so.

From http://www.nltk.org/data.html :

> Run the Python interpreter and type the commands:

```
> >>> import nltk
> >>> nltk.download()
```

> A new window should open, showing the NLTK Downloader. Click on the
>   File menu and select Change Download
>   Directory.

Then install the punkt model from the models tab.
Once you have that you can tokenize all sentences and extract the ones with your top 5 words in them as such:

```
sent_tokenize_list = nltk.sent_tokenize(text_string)    
for sentence in sent_tokenize_list:
    for word in list_5:
        if word in sentence:
            print(sentence)
```

Comment: I tried, how to remove this additional not necessary part from the output: output is:  ;}{\levelnumbers\'01;}\fi-360\li720\lin720 }{\listname ;}\listid1}}
{\*\listoverridetable{\listoverride\listid1\listoverridecount0\ls1}}
\margl1440\margr1440\vieww14360\viewh11020\viewkind0
\deftab720
\pard\pardeftab720\sl512\sa520\partightenfactor0

\f0\fs32 \cf2 \cb3 \expnd0\expndtw0\kerning0
\outl0\strokewidth0 \strokec2 in my previous refreshers, which you can access from the series navigation links at the top of this article, i talked

Comment: is that output part of the text file you are loading?

Comment: no. My text file starts as follows: "In my previous refreshers, which you can access from the series navigation links at the top of this article, I talked about two important Python concepts you need to grasp in order to move forward in your Python learning journey."

Comment: The other output you show looks like RTF groups. Try copying your text in a very basic editor like notepad on Windows and then use that new txt file as the input. Automatically extracting the text from an RTF is probably a different question.

Comment: thanks for input, however, I am not using RTF format the text I mentioned in later comment belongs to test.txt file, i.e it is extracting data directly from text file

Comment: Several of the strings in your example are definitely RTF control words. You can verify in the RTF specification here: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=10725&6B49FDFB-8E5B-4B07-BC31-15695C5A2143=1

Comment: thank you for correcting me although the file was in .txt file when I dragged and dropped it in py charm compiler it messed up with the formatting. I created text file using py-charm and copy pasted the RTF file in it, did the trick

Comment: If this or any answer has solved your question please consider accepting it by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this. Thanks!